# PHP with Vue CLI how to set vue.config.js

Tags: php, vue.js, proxy

Trying to Use PHP with Vue CLI, I'm trying to replicate this :
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-php-with-vue-cli/52842/3
but failed.

I have this folder structure:

1. myapp/

   - public/
   - src/
   - vue.config.js
2. back/

   - index.php

When I run `npm run serve` from myapp/, I go to http://localhost:8080 and see my app.

In an other folder called 'back', I have my php file(s).
I run a server with mamp and I access this folder at this address : http://back:8888

In my vue.config.js I have

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://back:8888',
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

From what I understood, I should have the same page when I go to http://localhost:8080/api and http://back:8888.

But I don't, I get a 404 for http://localhost:8080/api, and back:8888 is fine.

In the terminal I have this `[HPM] GET /api -> http://back:8888`
So it does detect a redirection.

The weirdest thing is that with this :

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://back:8888/index.php',
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

when I visit localhost:8080/api, I do have the output of the index.php in my back folder.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I add miss read the https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-php-with-vue-cli/52842/3.

localhost:8080/api == http://back:8888/api, and NOT like I though :
localhost:8080/api == http://back:8888.